# PHP: Can't append onto value

Tags: php, copy, rename, shell-exec

Im trying to make a program with winbinder that converts .iwd to .zip (its possible to do it just by renaming the .iwd to .zip) and i need to know how to take my varible that contains the file and make it overwrite the extension with a .zip

```
case 11:
            $filename = $GLOBALS["orig_filename"];
            $withoutExt = preg_replace("/\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/", "", $filename);
            $filename_with_zip = $filename."zip";
            echo shell_exec("rename ,"$filename" ,"$filename_with_zip"");
            echo $filename_with_zip;
        break;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Code:

Kudos to Almis for the original awnser, modified to fit your use a bit more and explained.

```
case 11:
     $iwd = $GLOBALS["orig_filename"];
     $zip = str_replace('.iwd', '.zip', $iwd);
     rename($iwd, $zip);
break;
```

### Explanation:

First of all, don't use `shell_exec()` for an already built in PHP function `rename`, usage here [php.net/rename](http://php.net/rename).

Second of all, `str_replace()` provides the ability to replace an param 1 with param 2 [www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

And lastly, don't use globals they can make problems harder to diagnose among other things ref. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557787/are...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557787/are-global-variables-in-php-considered-bad-practice-if-so-why) If you still decide to use them, I find it better to use `global $value` before needing the value in a separate function.

Answer (score 0):

You can change a file extension like that

```
$iwd = "C:/path/to/myfile.iwd";
$zip = str_replace('.iwd', '.zip', $iwd);
rename($iwd, $zip);
```